# Replacing/Upgrading brakes on ‘80s Peugeot road bike

Tags: brakes, upgrades, peugeot

I have a Peugeot road bike that I commute on every day. I’m not sure of the exact model, but from some digging around online I believe it is a 1986 or so. It has single pivot side-pull brakes, Shimano as I recall, the kind of generic silver kind that I think most bikes of this era had? Can figure out more specifics if necessary.
The other day while biking home, the pivot bolt (not sure the proper term) of the front brake broke, for some reason I can’t figure out. Sheared off about halfway between the frame and the front end. Calipers went flying, as far as the cable let them anyway.

My question is this: Rather than just getting a replacement bolt, would it be worthwhile to upgrade to a newer brake? The stopping power on them has never been that amazing, though some high performance pads I bought recently have helped a lot. I’m curious if a new brake would offer more stopping power, more structural integrity, or any other advantages? 
And if yes, how do I tell whether a brake assembly will fit? I know to measure the reach, but is there anything else that’s changed since the 80s to watch out for? I believe the brakes are unrecessed, for example, are those still manufactured? 
Any pointers or recommendations would be appreciated!

Comment: The newer dual pivot brakes are definitely a step up over the older single pivot, and would be worth it in my opinion.  You may need to ensure you have the right interface on the pivot bolt for your frame (usually length and whether or not the frame mount is inset). The mount interface has changed a bit over time.  You may need to go for a general brand (e.g., TRP) as Shimano has recently changed the pull ratio of their brakes (SLR) so it might not work great with older brake levers you have on your bike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mount recessed style brakes on your 80's frame by drilling out the hole through which the brake bolt goes on the backside of your forks such that the recessed style bolt fits through the hole.

You may have to get long reach style brake calipers in order for the pads to be able to reach the rim. These would be an option: [https://www.amazon.com/Tektro-R559-Calipers-Silver-55-73mm/dp/B006Z0OVWC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006Z0OVWC)
You can find cheaper models but in general the newer style (dual pivot) long reach brake calipers are more expensive than the standard reach models. You could potentially look for a second hand pair.

Another option (If you want significantly more braking power) is to replace the fork with a newer model which will work with normal range dual pivot calipers. These calipers have better leverage and therefore better braking power.